# How to go about creating a Java scheduled (repeating) app on AWS

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, scheduled-tasks

I want to write a basic Java app and have it run every 10 minutes on AWS (It will run a web service and check the returned data against data in a file which I also want to store on AWS (in S3 I think it must be stored).

Must I use AWS Data Pipeline and Task Runner to do this?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's easier and cheaper to have a permanent instance with a cronjob for every ten minutes..